# A serial of select (with group by), delete + insert, and stable explain plans is slowing down over time

Tags: sql, postgresql

On a `Postgresql 10.4` database I calculate some statistics on cities from data contained in a table containing 2,129,498 records and having these indexes :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_activites_des_communes_code_commune_salaries ON activites_des_communes(code_commune, nombre_salaries DESC);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_activites_des_communes_code_commune_ape ON activites_des_communes(code_commune, ape);
CREATE INDEX idx_activites_des_communes_ape ON activites_des_communes(ape);
CREATE INDEX idx_activites_des_communes_nombre_entreprises ON activites_des_communes(nombre_entreprises);
CREATE INDEX idx_activites_des_communes_nombre_salaries ON activites_des_communes(nombre_salaries);
```

An `ANALYZE` has been done on this big table.

In loops, for 36,000 cities, I execute for each cities these statements in sequence :

```
SELECT code_commune, nom, section_naf, 
       SUM(nombre_salaries) as nombre_salaries, sum(nombre_entreprises) as nombre_entreprises 
FROM activites_des_communes 
WHERE code_commune = :code_commune
GROUP BY code_commune, nom, section_naf 
ORDER by code_commune, nom, sum(nombre_salaries) DESC;
```

This request has this `EXPLAIN` plan :

```
"Sort  (cost=2141.72..2143.14 rows=568 width=36)"
"  Sort Key: nom, (sum(nombre_salaries)) DESC"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2110.05..2115.73 rows=568 width=36)"
"        Group Key: code_commune, nom, section_naf"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on activites_des_communes  (cost=28.84..2102.94 rows=569 width=28)"
"              Recheck Cond: ((code_commune)::text = '18205'::text)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_activites_des_communes_code_commune_ape  (cost=0.00..28.70 rows=569 width=0)"
"                    Index Cond: ((code_commune)::text = '18205'::text)"
```

Here, I do some calculation in memory, and I am ready to write a single record on a table that maybe empty or not. I start by deleting the target record, in order to replace it after.

```
DELETE FROM activites_section_des_communes_par_salaries WHERE code_commune = :code_commune
```

I have checked it's relative `SELECT` : it has for `EXPLAIN` plan :

```
"Index Scan using idx_activites_section_des_communes_par_salaries_code_commune on activites_section_des_communes_par_salaries  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=762)"
"  Index Cond: ((code_commune)::text = '18205'::text)"
```

Then, I do an `INSERT` and go for the next city.

At the beginning, my program is running fast :

```
2018-12-21 18:18:17.001  INFO 6040 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.c.f.m.application.ActivitesController  : Arboys en Bugey (01015) : Calcul des statistiques en cours.
2018-12-21 18:18:17.018  INFO 6040 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.c.f.m.application.ActivitesController  : Arbigny (01016) : Calcul des statistiques en cours.
2018-12-21 18:18:17.026  INFO 6040 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.c.f.m.application.ActivitesController  : Argis (01017) : Calcul des statistiques en cours.
2018-12-21 18:18:17.051  INFO 6040 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.c.f.m.application.ActivitesController  : Armix (01019) : Calcul des statistiques en cours.
2018-12-21 18:18:17.068  INFO 6040 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.c.f.m.application.ActivitesController  : Ars-sur-Formans (01021) : Calcul des statistiques en cours.
```

But doing its job, it slows down and slows down over time :

```
2018-12-21 18:53:11.088  INFO 5632 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.c.f.m.application.ActivitesController  : Lapouyade (33230) : Calcul des statistiques en cours.
2018-12-21 18:53:11.379  INFO 5632 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.c.f.m.application.ActivitesController  : Laroque (33231) : Calcul des statistiques en cours.
2018-12-21 18:53:11.671  INFO 5632 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.c.f.m.application.ActivitesController  : Lartigue (33232) : Calcul des statistiques en cours.
2018-12-21 18:53:12.254  INFO 5632 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.c.f.m.application.ActivitesController  : Latresne (33234) : Calcul des statistiques en cours..
2018-12-21 18:53:12.546  INFO 5632 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] f.c.f.m.application.ActivitesController  : Lavazan (33235) : Calcul des statistiques en cours.
```

Here are my questions :
**1)** My choice of indexes seems not clever to handle the request I want to run : the one having the `GROUP BY` and the `ORDER BY`.

**2)** How the slowing down, however, can be explained ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT code_commune, nom, section_naf, 
       SUM(nombre_salaries) as nombre_salaries, sum(nombre_entreprises) as nombre_entreprises 
FROM activites_des_communes 
WHERE code_commune = :code_commune
GROUP BY code_commune, nom, section_naf 
ORDER by code_commune, nom, sum(nombre_salaries) DESC;
```

The best index is on `activites_des_communes(code_commune, nom, section_naf)`.  This can work for both the `where` clause and the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Your reponse provided a boost to my application.
The part making it going slower and slower over time I just found it.
I missed to detach entities after persist in `JPA`.